# How to use gst-rtsp-server with own pipeline?

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer, rtsp

I am writing gstreamer application and need to transfer output audio/video stream over rtsp. But in `gst-rtsp-server` examples I have founded `factory` creation only by `gst-launch` syntax:

```
factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();  
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,
  "( appsrc name=mysrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");
```

Is it possible to connect `gst-rtsp-server` elements to my pipe?

Answer (score 7):

You have to subclass `rtsp-media-factory` and override `default_create_element` that will return your `pipeline` as `GstElement`

Comment: What do you mean by `rtsp-media-factory`? There's not a class with that name (and, AFAIK, there cannot be one due to C++ syntax)

Comment: @c.berger check https://github.com/tmatth/gst-prototypes/tree/master/gstrtspserver

Comment: @Étienne this is a good start, however this was implemented to target gstreamer-0.10 and many of the things it uses are private fields now

Comment: @DiegoRodriguez I agree that this is old code, but I was only replying to the question "what do you mean by rtsp-media-factory".

Answer (score 6):

After a lengthy research I was able to understand how to do this.

This snippet shows you how to override the virtual functions `GstRTSPMediaFactory` does, in this case were interested in overriding `create_element` and instead point it to our own static function responsible for returning the pipeline that you built when the internal mechanisms of `GstRTSPMediaFactory` need it.

See [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-rtsp-server/rtsp-media-factory.html?gi-language=c#virtual-methods) for other virtual functions that you can override.

```cpp
    GstElement binPipeline;
    
    GstRTSPMediaFactory *custom_pipeline_factory(GstElement *bin)
    {
      GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
      GstRTSPMediaFactoryClass *memberFunctions = GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY_GET_CLASS(factory);

      // pipeline created somewhere else
      binPipeline = bin;
      memberFunctions->create_element = create_bin_element;
      return factory;
    }
    
    GstElement *create_bin_element(GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory, const GstRTSPUrl *url)
    {
      return binPipeline;
    }
```