# Gstreamer pipeline from command lne to c code

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I wish to implement that command line in code. But "src." part => I didn't understand how to do. At gstreamer website there is a tee - queue sample but rtspsrc cant be link with tee element. And wherenever I remove decodebin it crashes.How can I code that ?

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov latency=10 name=src src. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink src. ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

Comment: In which language you are implementing `C` or `C++`. Tag question accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use gst-rtsp-server with own pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993373/how-to-use-gst-rtsp-server-with-own-pipeline)

Answer (score 1):

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch

`gst_parse_launch()` is an API call that basically translates your string pipeline which works with `gst-launch-1.0` into a pipeline object you can use in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i decided to use this too instead of creating each parts of pipeline.