# Gst-rtsp-server 1.0 how to use my own pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

I have finished read the userguide in the github of gst-rtsp-server,
I have found the demo always use such code to construct a static pipeline,

```
factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,
      "( rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:Admin12345@192.168.1.126 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 )");
```

but, if I want to use my own pipeline so that I could get the  GstElement* pointer of the pipeline for the next work, how should I do?
I have read the examples of gst-rtsp-server in GitHub,but it is  no help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gstreamer pipeline from command lne to c code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951411/gstreamer-pipeline-from-command-lne-to-c-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gstreamer pipeline from command lne to c code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951411/gstreamer-pipeline-from-command-lne-to-c-code)

Comment: What do you mean by "GstElement* pointer of the pipeline for the next work"?

Comment: @micha137 he means that he wants to have a pointer to the gstreamer pipeline so that he can apply other operations on it / call other functions.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993373/how-to-use-gst-rtsp-server-with-own-pipe, see http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/RTSP-Server-from-a-manually-created-and-linked-pipeline-td4680305.html and https://github.com/tmatth/gst-prototypes/tree/master/gstrtspserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use gst-rtsp-server with own pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993373/how-to-use-gst-rtsp-server-with-own-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your own pipeline you have to inherit `GstRTSPMediaFactory` and override `create_element` virtual member.
As example you could look at `GstRTSPMediaFactory` default implementation:
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-media-factory.c#L1636

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gst_parse_launch](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch), and input your custom pipeline you need. 
Also take a look at other functions provided in the link.

Comment: This cannot work without subclassing GstRTSPMediaFactory, the only available API "gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch" takes a string as parameter, not a GstElement.